# Is it possible to access to bluetooth handsfree mic/buttons from JavaME application?

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

Is there any way to use my bluetooth handsfree as JavaME app interface? I am looking for a way to use handsfree as additional, wireless input device. Is there any way to use my handsfree?

Comment: I am fairly sure that once your handsfree is connected to the phone, then JavaME will also react to whatever buttons exists on the handsfree. All you have to do is to figure out what keycodes they are, but I'm fairly sure they are mapped to the same buttons as on the phone. E.g. volume buttons will be the same, and receive call too.

Comment: Thats something. Thanks.

Comment: You right. Buttons are mapped equivalently. I think it may work. Thank you for answer!